# Installing AIDE on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: software-installation, security

I cannot seem to get this installed.

Using the following as root.

```
apt-get install aide
aideinit
```

I do have an exceptionally large mount point and would like to exclude this.

The process just seems to hang and there appear to be no logs.

Answer (score 1):

- Temporarily unmount your large mount point. (Unfortunately, this guide cannot be applied if temporarily unmounting is not possible.)
- Install aide.
- Add an exclusion to `/etc/aide/aide.conf`

  ```
  !/your/largemountpoint
  ```
- then mount it again.

There'll be a better way I'm sure but as no one has answered you yet in 2 months...

Comment: No risks, as long as you don't mind temporarily unmounting.
I just feel like it's not a very impressive answer!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited your answer to include hopefully a more exact version of the warning. Feel free to extend it but please leave out chatty text, write businesslike here.

Answer (score 0):

`aideinit` probably doesn't hang, but just takes ages due to your large mounted volume. Try **unmount** that large volume or **exclude** it with

```
!/your/largemountpoint
```

in a file `/etc/aide/aide.conf.d/00_local_excludes` and start `aideinit` again. Unfortunately `aide` only uses one CPU ([feature request](https://github.com/aide/aide/issues/12)), and per default calculates 7 checksums on each file, which is not always really needed.

Here are some examples how to configure `aide`:

## configure `aide`

The configuration files are `/etc/aide/aide.conf` and `/etc/default/aide`

#### edit `/etc/aide/aide.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/aide/aide.conf
```

you will see a line

```
Checksums = sha256+sha512+rmd160+haval+gost+crc32+tiger
```

which causes quite a lot of calculation power. I think one checksum is enough, change it to

```
Checksums = sha512
```

#### exclude some files and directories from scan

Add a file `/etc/aide/aide.conf.d/00_local_excludes` with excludes for all files and directories, that frequently change each day such as:

```
!/var/log.*
!/var/spool/.*
!/var/lib/vnstat/*
```

and folders, that probably won't make any problems, e.g.:

```
!/mnt/
!/media/
!/home/
!/backup*
```

- [/etc/aide/aide.conf.d/00_local_excludes](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/437636a27b58e4717a783740e599ce39) example file

#### edit `/etc/default/aide`

```
sudo nano /etc/default/aide
```

You can en-/disable the daily cron job in the line

```
CRON_DAILY_RUN=yes
```

if yes, change the line

```
MAILTO=mainname@example.com
```

(configure a local mail delivery for example with [`msmtp`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/527937/20661))

think about this line:

```
COPYNEWDB=no
```

`aide` stores the hashes of all monitored files in a database. At the next run, the newly calculated hashes are compared to the old hashes from the database and changes are noted. `COPYNEWDB=no` will never overwrite the old database. Ideally, the first database was created on a newly installed clean system. Thus, every run of `aide` shows the changes since the reinstallation. With `COPYNEWDB=yes`, the newly created database overwrites the old one. The files are thus always compared with the last run (i.e. the previous day). Changes over a longer period can be found in the log files of `aide` or in the daily e-mail reports.

```
TRUNCATEDETAILS=yes
FILTERUPDATES=yes
FILTERINSTALLATIONS=yes
```

If these three points are set to yes, you will receive a daily shortened email report. `aide` checks the log file `/var/log/dpkg.log` for this and hides changes due to package installations and security updates. This setting only affects the email report, the log file of `aide` still contains all changes to the system.

## initialize `aide`

```
sudo aideinit
```

The first database is created under `/var/lib/aide/aide.db.new`. Depending on the size of the system and the available computing power, this can take a while. From then on `aide` will always compare the new database `aide.db.new` with the old `aide.db`.

## first start

It will automatically start via cron but you can start it manually with:

```
sudo /etc/cron.daily/aide
```

*(source: https://www.techgrube.de/tutorials/mit-aide-einbrueche-auf-einen-ubuntu-server-erkennen )*

Comment: At the moment I get this error on Debian buster: https://github.com/aide/aide/issues/76, maybe this is fixed soon